# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset for inputstream

Tags: java, ssl, https

I am trying to download a file from https URL. I can able to download the file using the below code from  my home PC. However, I am unable to download it from corporate machine. Required `cacerts` already imported in java properly. I can also able to download the file from the browser. I've looked at the number of other threads but not able to figure out the appropriate solution for this problem. Here is my Java code

```
 try
  {
    url = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        else
            inputStream = httpURLConnection.getErrorStream();
 }
 catch (Exception ioe)
 {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Here is the exception which I got. I am always getting exception at `inputstream`. Remember this code is working 100% on my home PC.

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:706)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1593)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:352)
```

Any clue will be a great help.

Comment: Maybe the PC there is sitting behind a proxy?

Comment: Corporate PC has proxy but it doesn't require any authentication.

Comment: Some firewall rules maybe?

Comment: I think u still need to tell Java that a proxy exists, i had a similar problem

Comment: Try: `System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "host");
     System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "port");`

Comment: I did configured proxy with `System.setproprty` but no luck. I am getting the same error

Comment: I now tried it and setting the host and the port fixes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "host");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "port");
    try {
        URL u = new URL("some url");
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        InputStream is = null;
        if (huc.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            is = huc.getInputStream();
        else
            is = huc.getErrorStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: And u really have the right host and the right port? U need to replace the host with your host and the port with your port.

Comment: Yeah. I am using the same proxy in my browser as well as intellij

Comment: In what line do you get the Error?

Comment: This is where `httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()` I am getting error. In the debug mode I noticed inputstream as null

Comment: try to add this after the `u.openConnection()`: `huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
   huc.connect();`

Comment: I am pointing to work proxy host and port. All worked thanks for your suggestion